# Quotient by the canonical subgroup of an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

This question bothers me! Consider a $p$-adically complete and separated ring $R$, and an elliptic curve $E$ over $R$. It is clear that, if $E$ has ordinary reduction, then there exists a subgroup scheme of $E[p]$, the $p$-torsion of $E$, lifting the kernel of Frobenius. I also know, e.g. see Katz's "p-adic properties of modular schemes and modular forms", that this lifting exists also for elliptic curves not too supersingular. Usually this subgroup is called the canonical subgroup. Now, I see in a lot of papers that it is possible to consider the quotient $E/H$, where this $H$ is the canonical subgroup, but I don't see why this quotient is again an elliptic curve. First, why is the quotient representable by a scheme? And second, why does it satisfies the required properties for being an elliptic curve? Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Comment: It's a standard fact that the quotient of an elliptic curve by a finite subgroup is again an elliptic curve. See e.g. Silverman, *Arithmetic of elliptic curves*, proposition III.4.12.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! By the way, the reference you mentioned only deals with elliptic curves over fields. What's gonna happen if we consider elliptic curves over arbitrary rings? Is there an exhaustive reference for this case or the argument is simply a devissage? Another point, if you look at my previous question, I also have some problems with a suitable notion of Tate module. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much!